# How do I create a smart alarm clock?

Tags: smart-home, raspberry-pi, microcontrollers, sound

I have an old, broken alarm clock (speaker burned out) that I'm trying to make into a smart version. Can I use something like an Arduino or Raspberry Pi for this? What screen should I use?

I would like to have it controllable with an RGB LCD + buttons. I can write a web control panel to display things and play music. My concern is actually putting together the physical thing.

My alarm clock is GPX C303B.

People are asking for specific requirements. I would like the alarm clock to respond to buttons such as snooze and radio on/off, to be able to play a stream from Google Play Music, to display the time in large numbers, and also display alarms and the name of the current song playing.

The screen should be the same size as the original screen, which is 1.2 inches tall and [unknown, will measure] inches wide.

Pairing my phone over Bluetooth would also be acceptable to play music. I don't even need a web interface to set alarms. I'd be comfortable ssh'ing into it and setting cronjobs for alarms. I just want to display the time and alarms on screen, and if possible the playing song. Something like the Raspberry Pi Zero would suit me.

Edit: I have put in an Orange Pi Zero I have, along with a cannibalized speaker (that just happened to fit perfectly) and the electronics that were previously in the alarm clock. The Pi plays music via Mopidy and cronjobs.

Comment: In addition to this question being too general, I don't see that it is necessariy asking about anything which relates to connectivity. Feel free to expand on the question with more detail, since specific questions about design probably _are_ on topic.

Comment: What screen do you want to use, touch screen or LCD + buttons? What do you need the screen for; display time, date, weather, name-days? What are your specifications regarding the smart version. What would make the clock smart for you?

Comment: It's a very interesting question, can you please [edit](http://iot.stackexchange.com/posts/659/edit) the question to narrow it down(check comments made by @Aurora0001 and Bence Kaulics).

Comment: This question can be re-opened once you edit the question by narrowing it down the scope and giving more details.

Comment: Thanks for editing, but it's still quite a broad question at the minute, and would probably require a whole tutorial for an answer. You could easily ask this as multiple sub-questions that would be more narrow in scope, though, e.g. "Would an Arduino or Raspberry Pi be more suitable given the following constraints?" and "How can I determine which type of display unit would be appropriate for my problem?". I encourage you to ask questions like that, where we *can* give you a definitive answer more effectively.

Comment: Pick an RGB LCD you could use any of them. Then search for examples about how to interface it with a microcontroller (or Arduino or RPi or ESP8266). Once you have physical things to put together, we could actually help you putting physical things together. But before, there are just too many possibilities.

Comment: A raspberry pi is far too delicate in its configuration and complex a solution for this unless you have heavy compute or graphic requirements.  If you need wifi connectivity an Arduino is a bad choice, but an ESP8266 could be a good one.  If you need BTLE connectivity, you could use an Arduino with a module, but better to use a BTLE MCU... as already mentioned, you can't pick the platform until you have a specific requirement.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to re-create the Chumby.  If you really want to use Google's music streaming, then you'll be limited by platforms they let you run it on... perhaps a cheap prepaid phone rigged with a power supply in place of a battery?

Comment: As the comments suggest, this is a potentially interesting project, but describing the whole specification and build process is too big a topic for one question. Where would we stop with each detail? This could be a 20 video tutorial series, and still be too superficial.